# Добавление .html на конце ссылки рубрики Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rewrite

Как добавить *.html* на конце ссылки рубрики *Wordpress*?

Что есть: `/workers/proekty`

Что хотелось бы: `/workers/proekty.html`

Знаю что у *Wordpress* имеется `add_rewrite_rule`, и как его нужно подключать:

```
add_action( 'init', 'callback_rewrite' );
```

Но как полностью реализовать не могу понять.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule_my');
function rewrite_rule_my(){
add_rewrite_tag('%pagetype%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^(sitemap)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&pagetype=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

Нашёл у себя кусок кода, я думаю по примеру можно переписать

Comment: Да такой кусок кода и я писал. Только понять не могу. Пишу add_rewrite_rule('^/workers/proekty.html?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&pagetype=$matches[2]', 'top'); и что-то не то) Скорее всего с параметрами косяк какой-то. Какие вообще передаются параметры для отображения рубрики? в обычном GET запросе?

Comment: помоему только имя и тип, всё остальное для выборки! Надо у себя попробовать... но только на это надо время